# How magento link products to rules in catalog rule/sales rule

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm doing a magento extension which includes a same rules feature as the magento's native catalog price rule, that's to say you can set some conditions, then u can get all the products which matches those conditions.

But after checking around the magento's code, I couldn't find how magento link the products with rules, can someone point me out where are the codes that magento get all the products by the conditions ? (P.S.: I need the code that get products by conditions, not the codes get products by rule ID, I know that's get from database, but I'd like to know where're the codes that saves those records to the database.)

Many thx!

Answer (score 0):

Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule

This is the resource file that will interact with Db for catalog rule related aspect.

Comment: Yea but I didn't find code there, that's the file I check first, could u please tell the exactly place ?